# Table with horizontal scrollbar inside a fieldset

Tags: html, css, firefox

In my application, I have a fieldset containing table data.

The table might have many columns. 
So, to avoid that the browser window gets a horizontal scroll bar, 
I tried to wrap the table into a container with `width: 100%` and `overflow: auto`.

That didn't work. The fieldset still gets bigger than the browser's inner width, causing a scroll bar. I've tried to apply `width: 100%` to the `fieldset`. Even `position: absolute` with `left:0;right:0;` did not work.

Several tries later, I additionally added `min-width` and `max-width`, then it seemed to work. Well, it works in Chrome, Internet Explorer and Opera. But not in Firefox.

In Firefox, there seems to be no way limit the fieldset's width to the body width. Is there a way to work around this?

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 1em;
}
fieldset {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
table {
  display: block;
  width: 290em;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table input {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 100%;
}
td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10em;
}
.container {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Table Data
  </legend>
  <div class="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Year 2001</th>
        <th>Year 2002</th>
        <th>Year 2003</th>
        <th>Year 2004</th>
        <th>Year 2005</th>
        <th>Year 2006</th>
        <th>Year 2007</th>
        <th>Year 2008</th>
        <th>Year 2009</th>
        <th>Year 2010</th>
        <th>Year 2011</th>
        <th>Year 2012</th>
        <th>Year 2013</th>
        <th>Year 2014</th>
        <th>Year 2015</th>
        <th>Year 2016</th>
        <th>Year 2017</th>
        <th>Year 2018</th>
        <th>Year 2019</th>
        <th>Year 2020</th>
        <th>Year 2021</th>
        <th>Year 2022</th>
        <th>Year 2023</th>
        <th>Year 2024</th>
        <th>Year 2025</th>
        <th>Year 2026</th>
        <th>Year 2027</th>
        <th>Year 2028</th>
        <th>Year 2029</th>
        <th>Year 2030</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 2">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 3">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 4">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 5">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 6">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 7">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 8">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 9">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 10">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 11">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 12">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 13">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 14">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 15">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 16">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 17">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 18">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 19">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 20">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 21">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 22">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 23">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 24">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 25">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 26">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 27">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 28">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 29">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input value="Val 30">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: in snippet it works correctly

Comment: Have you tried it in Firefox/Firefox Developer Edition?

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with the following workaround:

When I replace the `fieldset`and `legend` with `section` and `h3`, the table renders as expected with a scroll bar. To make the section look like fieldsets, I defined a `.fieldset` class. This could be something like this:

```css
.fieldset {
  border: 1px solid silver;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.fieldset > h3 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: -0.5em;
}

/* content styling, not relevant to the workaround */
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="fieldset">
  <h3>Fieldset legend</h3>

  <!-- some content -->
  <p>
    <label>Foo</label>
    <input />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Bar</label>
    <input />
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Baz</label>
    <input />
  </p>

</section>
```

However, I really like the semantics behind `fieldset` and `legend` to group elements of a complex web form within named areas - that's exactly what fieldsets were made for (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset)).

Additionally, I didn't want to change the html structure, because it should be easy to revert to simple fieldsets. So I came up with a server-side solution that searches the DOM tree for fieldsets and replace them with my fake-fieldsets. An alternative to this approach would be to use features of a template engine, eg. "mixins" in [jade](http://jade-lang.com). In my specific use-case, it was just easier to replace the tags with a DOM manipulation library, because the html code has to be editable with a WYSIWYG editor.

Answer (score 3):

Adding `'min-width: inherit'` property to the `fieldset` makes it work.

Comment: For those wondering, you can also set `min-inline-size: inherit` because [according to the specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#styling_with_css) the default `min-inline-style` on `<fieldset>` is what causes this issue.