# How to prevent the images div from overflowing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]If I select multiple images, the div with class "images" overflows, I want it to be scrollable not to overflow and also want to keep the images aspect ratio, how do I do it?

**** Ignore this text, it's just filler text because StackOverflow says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." ****
**** Ignore this text, it's just filler text because StackOverflow says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." ****

```js
function init() {
  let files = document.querySelector("input[name='files']");
  files.onchange = filesChanged;
}

function filesChanged(event) {
  let imagesDiv = document.querySelector(".images");
  while (imagesDiv.firstChild) imagesDiv.firstChild.remove();

  for (let file of this.files) {
    let fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onloadend = () => {
      let img = new Image();
      img.title = file.name;
      img.src = fr.result;
      imagesDiv.appendChild(img);
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", init);
```

```css
* {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  word-break: break-word;
}

html,
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: .25rem;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.row {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
}

.gap {
  gap: .25rem;
}

input,
textarea {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  padding: .5rem;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  min-height: 10rem;
}

.form {
  background-color: bisque;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 62.5rem;
}

.form fieldset {
  border: none;
  padding: .5rem;
}

.form label {
  color: gray;
  font-size: small;
}

.images {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: start;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.images:empty {
  display: none;
}

.images img {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 150px;
  max-height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<form action="#" class="form">
  <fieldset class="column gap">
    <div class="column">
      <label>Title</label>
      <input type="text" name="title">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <label>Details</label>
      <textarea name="details"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="column gap">
      <input type="file" name="files" multiple accept="image/png, image/jpeg">
      <div class="row gap images"></div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: The "images" div in your example already scrolls. Adding ".images img { aspect-ratio: 1; object-fit: cover; }" To maintain image aspect ratio and prevent distortion.

Comment: No, the images div does not scroll, you see the horizontal scrollbar in the running snippet because the images div overflows past the form's width, but if you run the code in a larger screen you'll see what it actually does.

Comment: I added an image of the result.

Comment: The lower image shows that the div overflows when it has multiple images but it does not make it scrollable.

Comment: The fieldset tag is not constraining the width properly, allowing the div expand the page width without scrollbars. Duplicate of [Table with horizontal scrollbar inside a fieldset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892475/table-with-horizontal-scrollbar-inside-a-fieldset)

Comment: By the way, I disagree with the downvote, this is a great question and an interesting problem. It's fully reproducible. I also think it's technically a duplicate so it's more appropriate to close as dupe.

Comment: I don't see the solution to my problem, show me your working solution.

Comment: @JorgeZ as the duplicate question shows, add `min-width: inherit` to the fieldset tag fix your issue

Comment: Yes!, it does work... But I don't understand why, can you explain?

Comment: It looks like it's because a fieldset has the little-known `min-inlinesize` [style set on it by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset).

Comment: I'll look into that to try to understand it better, appreciate it!